# Displaying rounded images in github pages for profile image (using markdown)

Tags: github, github-pages, github-flavored-markdown

I'm trying to display circular/rounded images using markdown in my github page.
Right now i'm able to display image as shown here,
[check this please](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UbjqJ.png) But i need the image to be like this,[here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QB7r3.png)

Check out my github page, [here](https://suhasbrao.github.io/about.html) still working on it

I did search on the internet and found several articles all of them used HTML and CSS to display round images [On w3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_rounded_images.asp). But I want to display the image using markdown.
Is there away to display Circular images using markdown.
I'm a noobie here, please help me.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Not sure if this will work for you, but what I have done is use images.weserv.nl service:
https://images.weserv.nl/?url=avatars.githubusercontent.com/u/65769327?v=4&h=300&w=300&fit=cover&mask=circle&maxage=7d

You can adjust the height and width. It will generate something like this:
[image: avatar]

Markdown:

```
![avatar](https://images.weserv.nl/?url=avatars.githubusercontent.com/u/65769327?v=4&h=300&w=300&fit=cover&mask=circle&maxage=7d
)
```

Comment: Cool. Glad to hear.

Answer (score 4):

Another way is to download an image editing software like [GIMP](https://www.gimp.org/) and mask out a circle. Then remember to export as a PNG with transparency, but the images.weserv.nl service is a great way to do it assuming the service never goes down

Comment: Regarding weserv.nl going down, I have not had that issue. You could create a GitHub Action that does it every so often and writes the image to a static file for a GitHub repo and then retrieve that. A set of try/except with `response.raised_for_status` should suffice. The one issue there is that it won't be the latest avatar image.

Comment: Thanks Andrew, for your reply.